# How To Set Value In <style> ... </style> According To Browser Type Got From Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my site I need to set a value in `<style>...</style>` according to the browser type value I got in a JavaScript.

[1] How/where to run this browser detecting script ?

[2] What is a correct syntax to use the browser value in the `<style> ..</style>` section ?

My `<style>` and JavaScript look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_BrowserType()
  {
    // Opera 8.0+
    var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

    // Firefox 1.0+
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

  }
</script>

<style>
  .pic-container-1{display:block; position:relative; }
  .pic-container-1 .pic-box{display:block;}
  .pic-container-1 .pic-box img{display:block;}
  .pic-container-1 .pic-hover{position:absolute; top:0px; left:[ HOW TO SET VALUE ACCORDING TO BROWSER TYOE ? ] px; display:none;}
  .pic-container-1:hover .pic-hover{display:block;}
<style>
```

My HTML looks like this :

```
<html>
<body>
...
              <div class="pic-container-1">
                <div class="pic-box"><img src="GATE_Frame_1.PNG" alt="GATE"></div>
                <div class="pic-box pic-hover"><img src="GATE_Frame_2.PNG" alt="GATE"></div>
              </div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The "left" value in ".pic-container-1 .pic-hover" needs to be adjusted according to browser value, how to do it ?

Comment: You *should* be using CSS Vendor prefixes ..  That way you have control if An IE user comes in there, say `border-radius` doesn't act the way you'd like it to ..  Here is a great read: https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867

Comment: If you only have the element I would just manually change the left style value in JS, but if there maybe more than one, you can put a default value in the style tag, then come back in JS and create a new style tag that overrides the old one with the left value adjusted.

Comment: you may be interested in [lessjs](http://lesscss.org/)